# Plotting several 2d functions in a 3d graph

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, 3d

I am trying to reproduce a similar figure to the following one. My first guess was to use `pgfplots` but I didn't find any example that I could use as a starting point. At the moment I am unsure if `pgfplots` is actually the right package or I should rely on something else e.g. `TikZ`.

Since I don't really know where to start, I would appreciate any piece of code that points me in the right direction.

[image: Plot]

**EDIT**

Here is some dummy data for the plots.

```
plot1   plot2   plot3   plot4
0       0       0       0
3.466   2.058   0       0
4.262   2.976   0.001   0
3.822   3.168   0.006   0.008
2.953   2.936   0.019   0.063
2.065   2.492   0.046   0.265
1.332   1.977   0.092   0.734
0.797   1.478   0.164   1.508
0.443   1.045   0.268   2.44
0.228   0.698   0.412   3.219
0.107   0.438   0.598   3.524
0.046   0.256   0.831   3.219
0.017   0.138   1.109   2.44
0.006   0.067   1.429   1.508
0.002   0.029   1.78    0.734
0       0.01    2.141   0.265
0       0.003   2.479   0.063
0       0.001   2.736   0.008
0       0       2.808   0
0       0       2.465   0
0       0       0       0
```

Comment: `pgfplots` is certainly an appropriate choice for this. Note that `pgfplots` is based off the `pgf/tikz` package. For your particular image, you'll be using `\addplot3....`, and to get the curves in the `x-y` plane you could use `\addplot3` but with `z=0`. If you could provide more information (such as formulas, or data points, or what you've tried so far), folks might be able to help with more detail :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Tabulated data can be plotted in different planes quite easily by using `\addplot3 table [y expr=<value>, z=<name of column in table>] {<file name or table macro>};`.

You can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{<list expression>}{...}` to repeat the plot commands. Here's an example of how to plot your dummy data:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
plot1   plot2   plot3   plot4
0       0       0       0
3.466   2.058   0       0
4.262   2.976   0.001   0
3.822   3.168   0.006   0.008
2.953   2.936   0.019   0.063
2.065   2.492   0.046   0.265
1.332   1.977   0.092   0.734
0.797   1.478   0.164   1.508
0.443   1.045   0.268   2.44
0.228   0.698   0.412   3.219
0.107   0.438   0.598   3.524
0.046   0.256   0.831   3.219
0.017   0.138   1.109   2.44
0.006   0.067   1.429   1.508
0.002   0.029   1.78    0.734
0       0.01    2.141   0.265
0       0.003   2.479   0.063
0       0.001   2.736   0.008
0       0       2.808   0
0       0       2.465   0
0       0       0       0
}\dummydata

\begin{axis}[
    samples=30,
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,4},
    zmin=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=orange!80!black,thick,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
    }
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,3,...,1}{
    \addplot3 [area plot] table [x expr=\coordindex, y expr=#1, z=plot#1] {\dummydata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

And here's an example of plotting a couple of functions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples=30,
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick=data,
    zmin=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=none,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
        smooth
    }
]
\addplot3 [black, thick] table {
0 4 0
-0.75 3 0
-1.9 2 0
-1.2 1 0
};
\addplot3 [area plot] (x,4,{normal(0,1)});
\addplot3 [area plot] (x,3,{normal(-0.75,1)}) -- (axis cs:-4,3,0);
\addplot3 [area plot] (x,2,{normal(-1.9,0.7)}) -- (axis cs:-4,2,0);
\addplot3 [area plot] (x,1,{normal(-1.2,1.2)}) -- (axis cs:-4,1,0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I think at the back wall (!?) you can sum the columns and plot that too for the original cumulative effect.

Comment: i ll be thankful to you if u give me the codes fr matlab fr the same process of arranging 2d grapphs in 3d plot

Comment: @upendran [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.