# 2d graphs in a 3d plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create 3d plots with several 2d graphs, like in [Plotting several 2d functions in a 3d graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph). However the end result looks like this:

[image: Filling should be below the plot, not above!]

Using `\closedcycle` doesn't help either, as it generates this:

[image: Ugly line connecting last point of the last plot to the first point of the first plot]

The following is a MWE for the second figure, with a reduced dataset:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
q   1h  2h  3h  4h
0.01138 124.153702  119.550705  117.984253  115.065399             
0.089615    4.255316    4.356256    4.253153    4.040073       
0.129441    4.262549    3.756256    3.765975    4.120948       
0.254584    2.837865    3.107194    2.983951    2.531952    
0.298655    2.638327    2.848219    2.792608    2.729832        
}\data

\begin{axis}[
    zmode=log,
    log origin z=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=blue!70!violet,thick,
        fill=blue!70!violet!50,
        mark=none,
    }
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,3,2,1}{
  \addplot3 [area plot] table [x=q, y expr=#1, z=#1h] {\data} \closedcycle;

}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I get this straight?

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your example data, I can't compile your MWE (`Table '<inline_table>' appears to have too many colum
ns in line 2: Ignoring '121.330681'`). Could you fix that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved by an update of the package pgfplots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is solved in the now released v1.13 of PGFPlots. Your example now works without any changes.

It was also added a similar example to the manual in section 4.6.3 on page 130.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if there is a bug. If there is, take this as a workaround; I added redundant points in the curves and removed the contour lines (code below).

[image: areaplot3d]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
q   1h  2h  3h  4h
0.01138 124.153702  119.550705  117.984253  115.065399             
0.089615    4.255316    4.356256    4.253153    4.040073       
0.129441    4.262549    3.756256    3.765975    4.120948       
0.254584    2.837865    3.107194    2.983951    2.531952    
0.298655    2.638327    2.848219    2.792608    2.729832 
0.298655    1       1       1       1       
0.01138     1       1       1       1
0.01138 124.153702  119.550705  117.984253  115.065399
}\data

\begin{axis}[
    zmode=log,
    log origin z=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=blue!70!violet,thick,
        fill=blue!70!violet!50,
        mark=none,
    }
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,3,2,1}{
  \addplot3 [fill=blue, opacity=0.5,draw=none] table [x=q, y expr=#1, z=#1h] {\data} \closedcycle;

}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a bug: `\closedcycle` in a 3D context doesn't really make sense anyway (except for this rather special case). I think your approach of adding support points is exactly right (it's what I did in my answer to the linked question as well).

Comment: I agree. I kind of knew that using `\closedcycle` was a mistake form the start, since the pgfplots manual says it might not be a good idea and suggests using `--cycle` instead. But in my case it's even worse and leads to another version my first figure...

I was kind of hoping for a more elegant solution, but I might need to just go with alfC's idea (which is fine, by the way, it does what I need and that's what matters. No offense meant ;)

Comment: @Jake, yes, it looks like it. The log scale is not the problem even. BTW, I couldn't figure out how to draw the contour of the 3D surface.