# addplot3 [area plot] filling the wrong area

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

using some saved data, i use (The data file cane be download from [pX.txt](https://gist.github.com/farouqM/9313403) where the first column is the x and at each iteration, I plot the other columns with respect to the first column)

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{pX.txt}\datatablePX%          

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    zmin=10^5,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=black!50!black,
        fill=blue!50,
        mark=none,
    },
    xlabel={$x[m]$},ylabel={Time},zlabel={p[bar]}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{120,119,...,1}{
  \addplot3 [area plot]  table [x index=0, y expr=#1, z index=#1] {\datatablePX};
}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to plot some data in 3d, where I want the area under the curves to be filled. However, the wrong area is being filled as one can notice in the following plot.

[image]

It is filling the area to a line plot between the start and the end values. Why doesn't it simply fill with respect to the x-axis?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Still not compilable, due to lack of `pX.txt`.

Comment: @HenriMenke , I know, but the data file is very large and I cannot trancate. My question is if there is any extra argument to addplot3[area plot] whci will force it to fill to a given axis

Comment: Use [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) to upload huge text files and put the link here, like in ``[`pX.txt`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9035028)``. My approach would be to try to cycle the path manually be using `rel axis cs`.

Comment: @HenriMenke , done. But if you can provide a simple example on how to use the 'rel axis cs' , that would be very helpfull, as I can't find it in the doc

Comment: This has been asked and solved before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84875/1871, the trick is to close the cycle manually (adding a couple of base points explicitly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to cycle the path by hand, which is definitely not the best solution, but it works. So I'm doing the following:

```
\addplot3[area plot] table[x index=0,y expr=#1,z index=#1] {\datatablePX}
-- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin})
-- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin})
-- cycle;
```

This will look horribly with `enlargelimits=true`, so it is best to set your limits by hand or using `enlargelimits=false`.

If you don't want to use `zmin` for the lower filling boundary, you can specifiy an own key, e.g. `zcycle` and use the values assigned to this key. See the MWE for details.

## Implementation

I also tweaked your code a little, to have a little more speaking axis labels. Use [`pX.txt`](https://gist.github.com/farouqM/9313403), uploaded by OP. *I didn't plot all values for better performance.*

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\tikzset{
    /pgfplots/zcycle/.initial=,
}
\pgfplotstableread{pX.txt}\datatablePX%          
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            zmin=0.95*10^5,
        zcycle=10^5,
            area plot/.style={
                fill opacity=0.75,
                draw=black!50!black,
                fill=blue!50,
                mark=none,
            },
            xlabel={Distance $x$ [m]},
            ylabel={Time $t$ [s]},
            zlabel={Pressure $p$ [bar]}
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{120,80,...,1}{
            \addplot3[area plot] table[x index=0,y expr=#1,z index=#1] {\datatablePX}
            -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zcycle})
            -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zcycle})
            -- cycle;
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: your method is working well for this data. What if I would like to enter the z value manually? I have just changed `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}` by `MyValue` , but he is not considering it at all!

Comment: @user2536125 See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your intended use-case requires modifications to the input data.

In order to find a "suitable" modification, you need to understand what is going on here. Adding "fill" to the option list means that the path will be closed and the closed segment will be filled. Closing a path means to connect to the most recent "move to" path segment, where "move to" means "the starting point of the current segment" and "connect" means to connect with a straight line. This is what you see: for each segment, the last point is connected with the first one in order to close the path.

Thus, you can add additional coordinates to each scanline of your data - lines which ensure that the "last point" is equal to the first point of the segment.

For two--dimensional plots, `pgfplots` has the same requirement and it satifies it using the `\closedcycle` path instruction (compare the manual in section Area Plots). For three-dimensional plots you would need to do this on your own in the input files.

Any automated solution would be a feature request.

Comment: I cycled the path "semiautomated". For a limited use case, see my answer.