# Logarithmic y-scale with zero bin value

Tags: pgfplots

I have some trouble with an histogram filling when I plot it with `ymode=log`. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmode=normal,
      ymode=log,
      log origin=infty]
    % Draw series plot
    \addplot[red,fill=red!70,fill opacity=0.2,const plot] coordinates {
        (2, 20335)
        (2.048, 15937)
        (2.096, 12430)
        (2.144, 9469)
        (2.192, 6848)
        (2.24, 4913)
        (2.288, 3428)
        (2.336, 2276)
        (2.384, 1582)
        (2.432, 884)
        (2.48, 494)
        (2.528, 269)
        (2.576, 134)
        (2.624, 65)
        (2.672, 18)
        (2.72, 1)
        (2.768, 2)
        (2.816, 3)
        (2.864, 0)
        (2.912, 0)
        (2.96, 0)
        (3.008, 0)
        (3.056, 0)
        (3.104, 0)
        (3.152, 0)
        (3.2, 0)
    }
    \closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me that result

[image]

The last bin arround 2.8 jumps due to the fact that the next bin value is 0 and thus not "plottable" in log scale. I know how to solve this issue by replacing `(2.864, 0)` to something like `(2.864, 1e-6)`. Nevertheless, I would like to automatically change zero value within an histogram by let's say an epsilon shift to avoid such issue (my plots are generated by a third-party software and I would like to avoid editing the produced LaTeX file).

So far, I have try to use `y filter/.code` trick in order to add a small epsilon value to each `y` value by writing something like

```
\addplot[red,fill=red!70,fill opacity=0.2,const plot, 
         y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+1e-6}]
```

but this shift every bin by 1.

Comment: The problem with your epsilon trick is that the `y filter` works in the logarithmically transformed domain, which is why you end up with a line very close to `1e0`. In your real application, do you use `\addplot coordinates` (with brackets around the coordinates) or `\addplot table`? If the latter is the case, you can use `\addplot table [y expr=\thisrowno{1}+1e-6] ...` to add the epsilon to the untransformed values.

Comment: I use `\addplot coordinates` as shown in the example. I am not sure I get the logarithmic transform explanation : you mean that pgfplots is actually doing log10(\pgfmathresult)+1e-6 ? This does not lead to 1. Should I use an exponential transform ?

Comment: It's doing `ln(<y coordinate>) + 1e-6`. The coordinates with a value of zero are filtered out, which results in `<nothing> + 1e-6`, which, when transformed back, is very close to `1`. Can you teach the third party software to generate a more "normal" table format (without the brackets)?

Comment: I can and then I can add your `[y expr=\thisrowno{1}+1e-6]` to the `\addplot table` expression. So this solved my problem. How to proceed to validate your comment/answer ? Can you post your comment as answer in such a way I validate it ?

Comment: Try using the `restrict y to domain=ymin:ymax` option (documented in the `pgfplots` manual). I think there is no need to apply a filter/expression operation.

Comment: @alfC this breaks all the filling area. The plot looks like a cubist painting à la Picasso ;)

Comment: @XavierGarrido, I see, well, that is another problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84863/2d-graphs-in-a-3d-plot. Can you convert the `0` to `nan` and skip `nan`s (there is an option for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your epsilon trick is that the `y filter` works in the logarithmically transformed domain, which is why you end up with a line very close to `1e0`: It's doing `ln(<y coordinate>) + 1e-6`. The coordinates with a value of zero are filtered out, which results in `<nothing> + 1e-6`, which, when transformed back, is very close to `1`.

If you can format the data table to use a "conventional" format (no brackets around the coordinates), you can use `\addplot table [y expr=\thisrowno{1}+1e-6] ...` to add the epsilon to the untransformed values.