# How to make 3D ribbon plots in PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'd like to make a bunch of 3D ribbon plots in TikZ or PGF, I've taken a look around and I've found no hints on how this might be accomplished, is there a simple way to do this? I'd settle for a 3D waterfall plot which may be easier to achieve. 
My data is formatted thus:

```
theta -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

[image: 3D ribbons from origin]

Comment: Very closely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53795/2552 (using line plots instead of ribbon plots)

Comment: Did the link provided by Jake help you to solve your problem?