# PGF table plot waterfall diagram

Tags: pgfplots

## The Problem

I'm trying to create a diagram that is similar to this diagram generated by the matlab command `waterfall()`:[image]

The data for it is stored in a csv file. In this case it's 129 columns of data, the first one is just an index, the others contain the data for the 128 lines. The data used in the above image can be found [in this pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/fRETAs5T)

---

## What I've Tried

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.csv}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no markers,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 140,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 150,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 0.07,
    x dir = reverse]
    \addplot table[x = 1, y index = {0}, z index = {1}]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x = 2, y index = {0}, z index = {2}]{\mydata};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Basically, I'm trying to give each line a fixed `x` value and have it read the `y` and `z` values from the csv. For now I'm trying to add a few lines manually. Later I'd like to generate the addplot entries using some kind of for loop that.

Comment: Very related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53794/2552

Comment: Didn't find that one. I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: @Jake yes, that answered it. I have posted the working code as an answer. I don't know if I should flag this as duplicate or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [thread supplied by @Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53794/2552) I managed to solve the issue. I needed to import `pgfplotstable`. Then I can itterate using `pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and `x expr`. The working solution looks like this:

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.csv}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no markers,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 140,
    xlabel = {Polyphase},
    ymin = 0, ymax = 150,
    ylabel = {sample\#},
    zmin = 0, zmax = 0.07,
    zlabel = {Magnitude},
    x dir = reverse]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,128}{
    \addplot3 table[x expr = #1, y index = {0}, z index = {#1}]{\mydata};}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it produces the following output:
[image]

This still requires some fine tuning, but it works. For this to work I also had to increase the TeX memory. To increase the TeX memory in a miktex system open the relevant config file using `initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex`. Then add the following values, edit them to your liking if you want:

> pool_size=5000000
>   main_memory=6000000
>   extra_mem_bot=2000000
>   font_mem_size=2000000

Then remake the format files using `initexmf --dump=pdflatex`. [Source](http://blog.analogmachine.org/2013/08/12/how-to-increase-miktex-2-9-memory/).